# Does right-hand derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ where $x>0$ exist at the point $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have the function $f(x)=x^2$ defined for $x>0$ . Does right-hand derivative exist at $x=0$ ? By definition, it is equal to:
$$f'_+(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2-f(0)}{x-0}$$
And $f(0)$ is not defined for this function. so we say right-hand derivative not exist at $x=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thansk!

Comment: It does not make sense to ask if $f'+(0)$ exists if $f(x)$ is not defined at $0$

Comment: @PaxDaga I agree. That's kinda the definition somehow, though

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$ so can't be differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: So instead of this, is it true that $\lim_{x\to0^+} f'(x)=0$ ?

Comment: @Soheil: That’s correct. $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f’(x)=0$.